# R: DT development version: not possible to install

Tags: r, dt

i am trying **since few months** to install `DT` development version from https://github.com/rstudio/DT **without ANY POSITIVE RESULTS**

Currently i have installed the newest DT version 0.1 which is available on CRAN , but because of the limited options i need to update it to development version on github.

I have tried different approaches:

**1.** devtools

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```

straight away an error pops up in console message:

```
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/DT@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/DT/zipball/master
Installing DT
"C:/Program Files/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0k1umI/devtools16147de95516/rstudio-DT-24d71f2"  \
  --library="C:/Users/x/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Error: Command failed (1)
```

**2.** downloading zip file:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/x/Downloads/DT-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

No Error, but NO RESULT, it is actually ignoring much the command, in console appears:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/x/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

and thats it...

**3.** tar.gz

```
install.packages("C:/Users/x/Downloads/DT-master.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Even worse, error straight away appears in console, same like using `devtools` plus new thing:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/Program Files/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\x\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Users/asadm/Downloads/DT-master.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/x/Downloads/DT-master.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

It is really started to be annoying as since few months i am trying to figure it out (additionally some colleagues as well are facing the same problem)

I really do need updated version to development one, cause of many options of DT, which are not available in CRAN version (0.1) such as

- DataTable Extensions
- input$table_rows_all

**Does anyone faced the same problem and found a solution?**

**When the development version of DT will appear on CRAN?**

*I am able to install different packages from github without any error except `DT`...

Comment: Are you tried download zip ... extract ... use `devtools::install` to extracted folder?

Comment: Yes, same error like in 1.devtools: `> devtools::install("C:/Users/x/Downloads/DT/DT-master/DT-master")
Installing DT
"C:/Program Files/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/x/Downloads/DT/DT-master/DT-master" --library="C:/Users/x/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Error: Command failed (1)`

Comment: tried to do it under local admin on PC ( if its windows)?

Comment: me and my colleagues have already tried it (I have tried on Windows and my colleague on our RStudio version on linux server)..same problem...

Comment: Can you run R trought cmd ? "C:/Program Files/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" ( open widows cmd and paste path to your R like C:\R\R-3.2.5\bin\x64\R)

Comment: Perhaps there are other packages required before installing DT? just a wild guess, probably not it but worth a shot

Comment: @Batanichek, I cannot open R.exe but Rgui.exe works

Comment: @Bas i assume that required packages are the same as for the CRAN version DT, therefore i do have them installed

Comment: Which version of devtools you use?

Comment: ‘devtools’ version 1.11.1

Comment: I find one way on my home PC, Uninstal R . Re-instal R to path without spaces and not english char like `D:\R\`